# Callback inside nested function

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to understand [this code](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity#getAuthToken-caching)

I have simplified it with the code below and trying to understand how to use this function with a callback.

```
function test(text, callback) {
  function test2() {
    callback(text);
  }
}
```

And call it with

```
test('sometext', function(response) { 
  console.log(response);
});
```

However test2 never gets called.

How can I call test2 with this callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `text2`. All you do at the moment is define it. There are various ways you could do this. The simplest is to call the function where it is:

```
function test(text, callback) {
  (function test2() {
    callback(text);
  })();
}
```

Note the `();` at the end of the definition and the parentheses around it. This will call `test2` when `test` is run.

Another way to do the same thing is to call it after defining it:

```
function test(text, callback) {
  function test2() {
    callback(text);
  }
  test2();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `test` as a factory for `test2` and return it and call it at a later date:

```
function test(text, callback) {
  return function test2() {
    callback(text);
  }
}

var f = test('logged', console.log);

f();
```

In the example you link to it is not clear to me how the callback is called because it doesn't look like `getTokenAndXhr` is ever called. Perhaps there is some magic going on in the chrome browser that calls it via reflection of somekind.

Answer (score 1):

You never call test2, only declare it. Execute it explicitly:

```
function test(text, callback) {
    function test2() {
      callback(text);
    }
    test2();
}
```

Or since functionally there is no reason to declare a scoped function like this, just trigger the callback:

```
function test(text, callback) {
    callback(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually call `test2`.

You could put a call to it directly inside `test`. You could return `test2` and then call that return value later. etc.